# Update nested object in array MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, nestjs

I need to find and update documents with category that corresponding to the query. Array could contain mo than one corresponding id.

Query:

```
{
 "ids": ["61f1cda47018c60012b3dd01", "61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07"],
 "userId": "61eab3e57018c60012b3db3f"
}
```

I got collection with documents like:

```
`{

   "_id":{"$oid":"61f1cdd07018c60012b3dd09"},
   "expenses":[
     {"category":"61eafc104b88e154caa58616","price":"1111.00"},                  
     {"category":"61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07","price":"2222.00"}, 
     {"category":"61f1cda47018c60012b3dd01","price":"1241.00"}, 
     {"category":"61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07","price":"111.00"}
   ],
   "userId":"61eab3e57018c60012b3db3f"
 }`
```

my method:

```
  async myMethod(ids: [string], userId: string) {
try {
  const { ok } = await this.ExpensesModel.updateMany(
    {"userId": userId, "expenses.category": { $in: ids }},
    {$set: {"expenses.$.category": "newCategoryID"}}
  );
  return ok
} ........
```

I path array of ids ["61f1cda47018c60012b3dd01","61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07","61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07"] and userId, this code update only 1 category by document.

So can i made it with mongo build in methods? or i need to find matching document and update it it by my self and after that update or insert;

Answer (score 2):

Update with [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

```
db.collection.update({
  "expenses.category": {
    $in: [
      "61f1cda47018c60012b3dd01",
      "61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07"
    ]
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "expenses.$[elem].category": "61eab3e57018c60012b3db3f"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.category": {
        $in: [
          "61f1cda47018c60012b3dd01",
          "61f1cdb87018c60012b3dd07"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I8nbtBR-mXk)

Comment: your tip helped me move in the right direction, adapted it to my code, updated it a bit and everything worked, Thx a lot!

Comment: That's awesome!  If you wanted to assign `category` to the value of `userId`, how could that be done?  IOW, how could you replace the `arrayFilters` with something in a pipeline?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It would be better if you can edit your question with the exact needed. Make sure you want `update` the documents in db or `find` them out with `aggregate`.

Comment: Sorry, it's bad form for me to ask a question here in the comments since I'm not the OP, but I thought it might be a quick update to your mongoplayground.net contribution.  Just so I can understand better MongoDB `update`, how could the above be modified so that rather than having a "constant" ("61eab3e57018c60012b3db3f") be the new value, instead have the new value be `$userId`.  I tried just replacing the constant with `$userId`, but that didn't work, and `arrayFilters` don't seem to work with pipelines in `update`.